# Regular expression to find words with 3 or more capital letters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will search a string for any word that has 3 or more capital letters and I need it to return the entire word.

Comment: Do the three capital letters need to be consecutive?

Comment: Welcome  to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far that isn't working? This isn't a "please do my work for me" site; for that you need someplace like [RentaCoder](http://rentacoder.com). Here we're glad to help, but you need to show you've put at least some effort into solving it yourself first. It also helps, when you're posting your non-working code, to post some sample data so it's clear what you're looking for and what you expect to match. Please edit your post and add the additional information, so someone here can try and help. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help Phrogz. Sorry I should have added more information to my post. I had a regular expression that was getting the capital letters out of a word but I couldn't get one to return the entire word. I will be sure to add things that I've tried in future posts. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not too late to add it to this question, ya know :D (just click the word `edit` underneath the question, or click >[here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8069855/edit)<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/\b[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\b/
```

Tested (using Ruby):

```ruby
irb:001> re = /\b[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\b/
#=> /[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*/

irb:002> s = "The foo FooBar FooBarBaz ABC xABC ABCx aLongerTestWordHere said hi"
#=> "The foo FooBar FooBarBaz ABC xABC ABCx aLongerTestWordHere said hi"

irb:003> s.scan(re)
#=> ["FooBarBaz", "ABC", "xABC", "ABCx", "aLongerTestWordHere"]
```

Comment: +1, assuming the OP is happy with words that consist of ASCII letters only.